# Updating a User Field Using Axios and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have a user model with an array field called favorites

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  username: { type: String, unique: true },  firstName: String,  email: String,  passwordHash: String,  favorites: [Array]});
```

if a user clicks on an item i want the item to be saved in the user's 'favorites' field

here is button where I am handling onClick in a map where `card` is the singular item that a user is clicking on.

I also have a state called loggedUser which is saving state of the current logged in user.

```
onClick={addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
```

and the addFavorite handler:

```
const addFavorite = (card, user) => {
    props.updateUser(card, user);
  };
```

and then the action creator from my 'userReducer' file, which takes the card and user variables

```
export const updateUser = (card, user) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_USER",
      data: {
        card: card, user: user
      }
    });
```

and with my reducer, i'm saving the clicked user variable in a userToChange variable.  I'm then trying to concat the card data into the favorites array for the user.

```
   const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "NEW_USER":
      return [...state, action.data];
    case "UPDATE_USER":
      console.log("Action Data", action.data);
      const userToChange = action.data.user;
      console.log("User to Change", userToChange);
      const changedUser = userToChange.favorites.concat(action.data.card);
      userService.update(changedUser);
      return action.data;
    case "DELETE_USER":
      const removeObject = action.data;
      return state.filter(user => user.id !== removeObject.id);
    case "INIT_USERS":
      return action.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

when i click on the favorite button -- i get this error: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined  pointing to this line in the reducer:

```
 const userToChange = action.data.user;
```

Note here is also my axios put call

```
const update = async user => {
  const response = await axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${user.id}`, user);
  return response.data;
};
```

and my express route:

```
userRouter.put("/:username", async (request, response, next) => {
  const body = request.body;
  const updateUser = {
    favorites: [body.favorites]
  };
  console.log("updateUser", updateUser);
  console.log("id", request.params.id);
  try {
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(username, updateUser, {
      new: true
    });
    response.status(204).end();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

where might i be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you post the complete reducer?

you should have something like this in the definition:

```
function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, response, payload, data } = action
....
```

maybe you are not defining the action parameter in the reducer function, and of course your reducer does not know what means "action.data"

---- edited ----
are you doing this in a stateful or stateless component? Maybe you are doing the wrong call.

If you are using a stateless, do this:

```
onClick={() => props.addFavorite(card, props.loggedUser)}
```

If you are using a stateful, do this:

```
onClick={() => this.props.addFavorite(card, this.props.loggedUser)}
```

Comment: hi i just posted my full reducer above

Comment: i'm wondering if issue might be the fact that my user favorites array is empty?

Comment: i should note that my loggedUser state doesn't have the favorites field and i'm not setting that field when i create a new user

Comment: i edited my answer, check it. you might be calling the function the wrong way